# convert a promised variable to normal one - angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps

i want to share variables in my controllers. when i try to do so, the variable is converted to a promised one, even though i used the .then function.
all i want is to move the asd variable to the $scope map latitude and longitude values.
inside the getFoo() the console shows the data as it should be but on the out side of the function it shows promise.

my service:

```
.factory('getGoogleCoordinates', function($http) {
   return {
     getFoo: function(zip,street,city,state) {
       //since $http.get returns a promise,
       //and promise.then() also returns a promise
       //that resolves to whatever value is returned in it's 
       //callback argument, we can return that.
       return $http.get('http://maps.google.com/maps/api/geocode/json?address=' + zip + ',' + street + ',' + city + ',' + state + '&sensor=false').then(function(mapData) {
           return mapData;
       });
     }
   }
})
```

my controller:

```
.controller('mapCtrl', function(getGoogleCoordinates, myService2, $scope) {

    console.log(myService2.show3()[0].street);

    var asd = getGoogleCoordinates.getFoo(myService2.show3()[0].zip, myService2.show3()[0].street, myService2.show3()[0].city, myService2.show3()[0].state).then(function(data){
        console.log(data.data.results[0].geometry.location);
        return data.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat;
    });

    console.log(asd);

    $scope.map = {
        center: {
            latitude: 33.025859,
            longitude: -96.844698
        },
        zoom: 15
    };
});
```

Comment: you have to consume the data in the $http callback, it won't return from inside `then` to your variable `asd`

Comment: what do you mean? can you show me an example?

Comment: set your map data inside the `asd then()`

Comment: If is an angular map directive would pass your data to the markers method array

Comment: arr i dont understand what you're saying... im an angular newbie, please show me an example.i learn the best from examples :D

Comment: don't know what directive you are using. Follow the directive on how to set markers from scope and do the same with your data

Answer (score 0):

Do you use angular ui router? One example could be:

```
$stateProvider.state('myMapState', {
  controller: 'mapCtrl',
  templateUrl: 'map.html'
  resolve:{
    center: function(getGoogleCoordinates, myServivce2, $q){
        var deferred = $q.defer();
        getGoogleCoordinates.getFoo(myService2.show3()[0].zip, myService2.show3()[0].street, myService2.show3()[0].city, myService2.show3()[0].state).then(function(data){
            deferred.resolve( {latitude: data.data.results[0].geometry.location.lat,longigute: data.data.results[0].geometry.location.lon});
        });
        return deferred.promise;
    }
  }
}
```

And the controller:

```
.controller('mapCtrl', function($scope, center) {
    $scope.map = {
        center: center,
        zoom: 15
    };
});
```

Comment: this isn't worked either, and i generaly prefer to work on my controllers & services js files. im just not very familiar with all that ui router stuff. im using ionic-yeoman if that helps, could you show me another example?

Comment: using it with stateProvider and resolve will work! the center variable will be already resolved when the controller is constructed. if you want to do it later, you will have to set `map.center = ...` inside the then callback and initialize it before.